# Hover on item with box-shadow and transition causes overflow problems

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

In Microsoft Edge, when hovering to trigger a transition effect, you can see overlapping sections of the divs flickering into view despite `overflow: hidden` being set. Pretty strange, and it doesn't show on other browsers and platforms I've checked. Check the codepen link. I've included the most relevant bits of code just for quick reference but the snippet here won't show anything much.

Here's the most relevant code:

```css
.test01 .test01w2 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 22.457627118644%;
    padding-top: 22.457627118644%;
    margin: 0 0 0 03.389830508475%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f0f;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 22px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), -2px 2px 22px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.test01 .test01w3 {
    color: #fff;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 2;
}
.test01 .test01w3 ~ .test01triangle {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0.2s;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0%,103%) scale(3, 1);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.test01 .test01w3:hover ~ .test01triangle {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0%,103%) scale(3, 4);
}
```

```html
<div class="test01w2 bgdarkslate">
    <div class="test01w3">
        <a href="placeholder.html">
        <div class="icn-img icn-ondark icn-myaccount"></div>
        <h3>Ipsums and Lorems</h3>
        <i>&#8212;</i>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="icn-img icn-ondark icn-arrow">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="test01triangle"></div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/djameskennedy/pen/ZEERxom)

Comment: I try to test it with MS Edge and I am able to produce the issue. It can be possible that the issue is related to Microsoft Edge browser or it is Edge default behavior. I will try to submit the feedback regarding this issue. As a workaround, you could try to remove the `transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0.2s;` or delete the `box-shadow: 0px 0px 22px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), -2px 2px 22px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);`. If I get any solution or a work around than I will try to provide you in future. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks. It's just the overlapping sections of the transparent divs that are flickering into view for a second on hover. If you uncheck overflow: hidden on the .test01 .test01w2 div you can see.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, after removing the overflow attribute on the .test01 .test01w2, the result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Saqzq.gif), it only affects the hovered elements, not others. But if we add the overflow attribute, it will affect other elements, the result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMoDG.gif). it seems that the issue is not related the .test01 .test01w2 hidden attribute. And if we remove the transition(as said in my previous comment), the result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb9Bq.gif). it seems that it works well (without transition).

Comment: It works either without the transition or without the box-shadow as previously mentioned. Removing overflow hidden just allows you to see what's happening more clearly.